# laravel to MySql query not displaying accurate results

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

i tried to do this insert and update another table with the sum of the data and the new values, but im getting wrong results
please help me convert this laravel to sql.
thanks in advance:
laravel:

```php
$viaturas = Viaturas::firstWhere('matricula', $viaverde->matricula);
$viaturas->total_viaverde = $viaverde->custo + $viaturas->total_viaverde;
$viaturas->update();
```

sql not doing right as follows:

```
UPDATE `viaturas`
INNER JOIN `viaverde` ON `viaverde`.`matricula`=`viaturas`.`matricula`
SET `viaturas`.`total_viaverde` = (SELECT SUM(`viaverde`.`custo`));
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is `save()`

```php
$viaturas = Viaturas::firstWhere('matricula', $viaverde->matricula);
$viaturas->total_viaverde = $viaverde->custo + $viaturas->total_viaverde;
$viaturas->save();
```

If you use `update()`, you have two options

1. From the Model object

```php
$viaturas = Viaturas::firstWhere('matricula', $viaverde->matricula);
# update this $viatura model
$viaturas->update(['total_viaverde' => $viaverde->custo + $viaturas->total_viaverde]);
```

2. From the Query Builder

```php
# update every Viatura where matricula = $viaverde->matricula
Viaturas::query()
    ->where('matricula', $viaverde->matricula)
    ->update(['total_viaverde' => $viaverde->custo + $viaturas->total_viaverde]);
```

---

To run that specific SQL query from the query builder, I think this should do it

```php
Viatura::query()
    ->join('viaverde', 'viaverde.matricula', 'viaturas.matricula')
    ->update(['viaturas.total_viaverde' => DB::raw('select sum(`viaverde`.`custo`)')]);
```

Comment: thanks, how can i make this in mysql?? im havint trouble, it's working fine with update but ill try your method, i have an insert before the update query

Comment: i expressed myself wrong, i want to import some data to the phpmyadmin and run the update query like i have in the laravel app, to update i don't need to do it anymore in laravel or within the app it's just to be more convenient for me to import a data onto the tables so it get's represented correctly in the app